# why mod_rewrite is not working

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, cakephp

I enabled the mod_rewrite in apache by following this article :
http://www.lavluda.com/2007/07/15/how-to-enable-mod_rewrite-in-apache22-debian/
but still when i run the cake php folder it say :

```
URL rewriting is not properly configured on your server.

   1. Help me configure it
   2. I don't / can't use URL rewriting
```

What should i do?

I checked

```
apachectl -t -D DUMP_MODULES
```

it say rewrite module shared .

Comment: Enable log with `RewriteLog` and `RewriteLogLevel` and check it.

Comment: @quanta i tried for doing log by following commands RewriteEngine On
RewriteLog "/absolute/path/to/your/wwwroot/public_html/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 5 I added in apache2.conf at bottom , but then m not able to restart the apache it is giving me error why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a bug with cake php as per [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245865/cakephp-1-3-url-rewriting) and [this one](http://groups.google.com/group/cake-php/browse_thread/thread/bdacb97ad4e6a39c/e4d77578033da85d?show_docid=e4d77578033da85d).

-$

Answer (score 0):

Rahul,

set your apache main log to debug so that you can determine why apache isn't starting after adding the rewrite directives.